# how to switch workspaces in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: workspaces

When I move my laptop from place to place and switching on and off a second monitor. my workspace seems to mess up easily: I could not be able to bring up some terminal or browser window.

At first I thought these must have crashed, but now realize they are just in different workspaces. But I'm not able to switch to them. CTL+ALT + TAB should be able to do that, but it doesn't stay on. As soon as I hit ENTER key or mouse button the selected window just disappears. Nor do I see an "activities overview" anywhere on my screen.

What am I missing?  I have Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo T450s laptop. Everything else is fine.

thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Just go to System settings - Apparence - Behaviors, check the 'Enable Workspaces" button.